# Unfortunately, Google Play Games has stopped when trying to open leaderboard

Tags: android, google-play-games

I am trying to add a leaderboard to my application. My Google Play Services is connected for sure (log confirmed) and my leaderboard onclick is working fine, but my Google Play Services is crashing for some reason? I have the latest version of the application available on the play store. Not sure what's going on here..

Here is where I attempt to launch the leaderboard:

```
@Override
public void onLeaderboardButtonClick(View view) {
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        startActivityForResult(Games.Leaderboards.getLeaderboardIntent(mGoogleApiClient, leaderBoardId), 0);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Not connected. Connecting now..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
}
```

The activity shows up for a second with a dark blue background and then Google Play Services crashes. Any ideas what's happening here? I see some similar posts but they're from 2014 so I'm not sure just waiting for google to update is relevant anymore..

**Edit:** Here are the screenshots from when it happened. My app is not crashing, it's Google Play Services.

[image: what happens when I click on leaderboard]

[image: stacktrace]

Comment: Show the stack trace from logcat.

Comment: Please add logcat output from when the crash happens.

Comment: It's not my app that's crashing, it's Google Play Services. I edited my post with the screenshots. Thanks for any help!

Comment: would mind sharing your app id and which version google play services your are running on the device (and which one you are referring to in your build)?